# How to make the ListView properly move to the target position with a button?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-button

I have a ListView and I would like it to move to the target position everytime I click on a button.

The NextButton works fine, but there is an issue with the PrevButton.

Whenever I click on the PrevButton, the target position is always the first position of the new view after it's being scrolled to.

For example,
If I set this:

```
mListView.setSelection(5);
```

After the target position is scrolled to, the new view would be
position 5, 6, 6, 8, etc.

How can I make it to be the last position of the new view such as position 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

I know they can do that with default Gallery app

Code:

```
PrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Pre_Button);
        PrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ((BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                mListView.setSelection(LastItemPos - 1);
            }
        });

NextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Next_Button);
        NextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ((BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                mListView.setSelection(LastItemPos + 1);
            }
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: do you mean that listview is not getting scrolled to that position ? or do want by clicking on th button listview should be scroll to that requested position ?

Comment: @ user1140237, it does scroll to the target position.  The problem is after the target position is being scrolled to, that position is always the first position of the new view.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every View you have in your ListView is going to be the same height, all you have to do is figure out how high each View is going to be then divide it by the height of the ListView.

To figure out a View height just do inflate it, measure it with an "unspecified" measurespec, then get the measured height:

```
public int getItemHeight(ListView listView, int listViewItemId) {
  MeasureSpec widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeSpec(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, listView.getWidth());
  MeasureSpec heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeSpec(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, listView.getHeight());
  View listViewItem = LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.idOfListViewItem, listView, false);
  listViewItem.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
  return listViewItem.getHeight();
}
```

Then, figure out how many items are going to be positioned on the ListView.

```
int itemHeight = getItemheight(listView, R.layout.layoutIdOfItem);
int numOfItems = itemHeight / listView.getHeight();
```

Then, whenever you set the position, just subtract the number of items from the position. Although you have to make sure it doesn't go below 0.

```
int itemToScrollTo = 5 - numOfItems;
if (itemToScrollTo < 0) {
    itemToScrollTo = 0;
}
listView.setPosition(itemToScrollTo);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer DeeV.  Would you mind to tell me what R.layout.layoutIdOfItem is - is it the layout that I have in my MainActivity?  Thanks

Comment: It's the ID of the layout file. You inflate a view in the ListView's adapter, right?  Same thing here.  If you do it programmatically, then you can create a utility method in the adapter that programmatically creates the View items.  The only important thing is you need the View that's going to populate the ListView.

Comment: Oh no, I am sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using TwoWay-View from Lucasr.  I thought it was similar to ListView except it is Horizontal scroll instead.  I am not able to use TwoWayView..setPosition(itemToScrollTo);  :-(   However, I check the itemToScrollTo and it seems to give me the correct position out of the total # of items.  Do you happen to know if there is another method for setPosition()?  Thanks

Comment: No.  I have no idea what that is. Sorry.